# Local Node.js API failed to connect MySQL database that host on local Docker container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

Here I have problem. As I try to connect a MySQL database that host on local Docker container. Details of the container and docker-compose.yaml are shown as follows.

[image: Details of the container]

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: pm-mysql
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    #ports: '3306:3307'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  database_phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin-pm-mysql
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wackySee)71
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
```

Now I am using Node.js API with express to connect the MySQL database as follows:

```
// initialize parameters
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
require('dotenv').config();
// Mysql parameters
const mysql = require('mysql2');


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('testing get api');
});

// I use this API, API link: http://localhost/database/
app.get('/database/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("database")

    // Connect to MySQL
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: "test",
      password: "test",
      database : 'test',
      //port: "3306"
    });
    
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
    });

    // Read parameter
    tags = req.query.in;

    // Return JSON
    res.end(JSON.stringify(req.query.in));
  });

// Listen port 80
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('server: Listening on port 80!');
});
```

I ran the API with the commend "nodemon ./server.js localhost", then when I access "http://localhost/database/", it return the following error.

```
PM web server: Listening on port 80!
database
F:\PM_web_system\server\index.js:27
      if (err) throw err;
               ^

Error: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Packet.asError (F:\PM_web_system\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
    at ClientHandshake.execute (F:\PM_web_system\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
    at Connection.handlePacket (F:\PM_web_system\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)     
    at PacketParser.onPacket (F:\PM_web_system\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)        
    at PacketParser.executeStart (F:\PM_web_system\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16) 
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\PM_web_system\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000',
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
  sql: undefined
}
```

In the database, it has the follow accounts.

[image]

I can login through the mysql server and phpmyadmin on root and test account, but it is impossible for "root"@"localhost" and "test"@"localhost" through both Node.js and mysql server. I have checked the password is correct and already using mysql_native_password, no idea on why it has such problem. Also, I found the IP address of the MySQL container as "172.30.0.2", but it return timeout.

```
server: Listening on port 80!
database
F:\PM_web_system\server\index.js:27
      if (err) throw err;
               ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (F:\PM_web_system\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:189:17)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

What is the problem and how to fix it? I searched around but could not find an answer to my issue.

I have tried a lot of method that post on stackoverflow already, like change password and mysql_native_password.
I expect to find the basis of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I put the port number to the MySQL server part, and let the account that created which can access all host is available, then it is fine to solve the problem. But still needed further checking later on. BTW, thanks for your time for review my question.